# Why does Elm.embed only accept divs?

Tags: embed, elm

If you attempt to use `Elm.embed` with an element other than a `div`, you get this error:

> Elm.node must be given a DIV, not a BODY.

I can see that [this fairly explicitly](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3.0.0/src/Native/Runtime.js#L21-L24) in the source. I'd like to understand *why* this restriction exists. Why am I unable to embed Elm inside of my `body` tag, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Elm.embed` you're saying "I'm giving full control over the contents of this element to this Elm module". Trying to embed it into the `body` would be the same as using `Elm.fullscreen` (one of the [other ways](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop#other-ways-to-embed-elm) to run an Elm app).

As for why you couldn't embed in any other tag (say a `<span>` or `<p>` tag), my guess is that it is just to be semantically correct and avoid any weird behavior. A `<div>` is just a block element that "defines a section in a document". A `<span>` tag has similar semantics ("defines a section in a document"), but is not a block element (what would it mean to display this Elm module as an inline element?). A `<p>` tag is a block element, but is meant to hold a paragraph of text. What would even happen if you tried to embed in a `<canvas>` or `<iframe>` element? You can avoid all that by just ensuring that the element the app is embedded in is a `div`.